# Conditional ng-disabled in AngularJS 1.0.7

Tags: angularjs

is it possible to do something like:

`ng-disabled="x >= y"` but in case y == undefined then take z (another value) inside an ng-disabled expression in AngularJS 1.0.7?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, it will surely work

```
ng-disabled="x >= ( y == undefined ? z : y )"
```

Comment: I was aiming for a similar solution using this ternary expression: "x >= (y ? y : z)", but it doesn't seem to work in Angular 1.0.7

Comment: @Ajay I agre with Prince, it seems it doesn´t work in Angular 1.0.7. I get an error: Lexer Error: Unexpected next character